# Locating and extracting a substring to a new column in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and want to locate a key term in the column. If the row in the 'Jobtitle' column contains the term I want it to extract it and return it to a new column. I have attempted with the following code but am returning error so far

```
if 'engineer' in glassdoor['Jobtitle']:
    glassdoor['job_cat'] = glassdoor['Jobtitle'].str.extract('(engineer)', expand=True)
    glassdoor['job_cat']
else:
    print('error')
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? Can you share a small data to test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `np.where` +`contains`

```
glassdoor['job_cat'] = np.where(glassdoor['Jobtitle'].str.contains('engineer'), 'engineer', 'nothing')
```

Comment: thankyou, this works well. However, what would I need to do if I had more than one term e.g. engineer and say scientist?

Comment: @TC1111 check with df.join(pd.DataFrame(glassdoor['Jobtitle'].str.findall('engineer|scientist').tolist(), index=df.index))